# What is causing my new computer to make a chirping / clicking sound

Tags: computer-building

I recently built a new computer, and at first everything was okay, but once I started to load up Windows, I noticed this chirping or clicking sound. The computer does not make the sound while in the Bios and it occasionally goes away. See the link below.

[video demonstrating clicking sound](https://youtu.be/g8Dx02BIm10)

By the way at first you hear a clock in the background it is not what I am referring too.

What could be causing the sound?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik My main drive is an SSD so would the hard drive still be moving even when I'm not using it?

Comment: Can’t you stick your head in there and identify where it is coming from?

Comment: Or use a piece of rubber tubing or plastic straw as a stethoscope to find it.

Comment: Something too close to the fans?